# How to expose docker container port and call from postman?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops

docker-logs

6000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6000->80/tcp   vigilant_mclean

Trying to make a call from postman using url `http://0.0.0.0:6000/` i dont get any response.

Can someone please explain how docker port works when we run container.

DockerFile

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 6000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 6000
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const middleware = ('./middleware');
const middleware2 = ('./middleware2');


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
app.post('/v1', middleware, middleware2);


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Could you please show us your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @prithajnath added, trying to create very basic app with docker i was able to build image and run the container now i am not able to make api call

Comment: Is your `server.js` listening on port 80 of the container? Would help if you can also share that

Comment: Try http://localhost:6000 or http://127.0.0.1:6000 . 0.0.0.0 is not an IP adress is just an placeholder to tell you it is listening on all ip addresses of the local host.

Comment: @prithajnath added server.js as well

Comment: also add your docker run command. Because from the question it seems the container mapped container port 80 to your 6000 local port. But from the server.js you try to start the process on 6000.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like your `server.js` is listening on port 6000 of your container. You need to bind port `6000` of your container to port `6000` of your host (You're currently binding port `80` of the container to your host's port `6000`)

```
docker run -p 6000:6000 ... <image>
```

Also make sure your process is listening on host `0.0.0.0` (instead of localhost). Container's localhost is not the same as your host's localhost

```
app.listen('0.0.0.0',port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: ok i mapped it however this url still doesn't work `http://localhost:6000/v1`